# Why isn't Mary a victim of the permutation?

Tags: combinatorics

I've answered the following question:

> In a class, there are 8 female students in which one of them is called Mary and seven male students, in which one of them is called John. Considering comissions formed by 5 male students and 4 female students, how many of these contain Mary?

Then choosing Mary, I'd have: $(1*7*6*5*4)*(7*6*5*4)=705600$ now I'll have to discount the repeated permutations $705600/4!*4!=1225$. I know that whenever I have a *locked choice* like Mary, I'll have to permute by $4$ instead of $5$. I know it works but I don't understand why it should be done.

Rephrasing it in a shorter version: Why $705600/4!*4!$ instead of $705600/5!*4!$?

Comment: For the same reason you would divide by $5!4!$ instead of $9!$. If you prefer, you actually divide by $1!4!4!$ (Maries, non-Mary females, males)

Comment: You are really dividing by $1!4!4!$, since there are three groups of people to consider; Mary, female non-Marys, and male students.

Comment: I am confused. Why do you have $(1*7*6*5*4)$ for choosing Mary, when you are only suppose to select 4 female students? And even if this were for the males, are you picking John???

Comment: I think that you're using "victim" wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$5$ students are chosen from $7$ male students: $\binom{7}{5}$ possibilities.

$3$ students are chosen from $7$ female students (Mary is excluded): $\binom{7}{3}$ possibilities.

$1$ student is chosen from $1$ (Mary): $\binom{1}{1}$ possibilities.

That gives $\binom{7}{5}\times\binom{7}{3}\times\binom{1}{1}$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you "choose without replacement", then you need not "discount the repeated permutations":

- Choose $5$ out of $7$ male students: $\binom{7}{5}$
- Choose Mary
- Choose $3$ out of the remaining $7$ female students: $\binom{7}{3}$

Now simply multiply the number of male combinations by the number of female combinations:

$$\binom{7}{5}\cdot\binom{7}{3}=\frac{7!}{5!\cdot2!}\cdot\frac{7!}{3!\cdot4!}=735$$

The only question remaining is, what has John got to do with all this???

Comment: It might be that John fancies Mary and is doing everything he can to be elected.

Comment: John is *used* in the latter questions. I forgot to take him out of the playground.